# Just need a little guidance on functions in swift 3

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I've created a simple tip calculator using Swift 3. After 5 solid hours of trying to consolidate the functionality of every button's action to one function, I came up dry. So every button is hard coded now. I have uploaded the [VC file](https://github.com/joeavargas/JustTheTip/blob/master/JustTheTip/ViewController.swift) to github for your reference. As you can see starting on line 15, that was my attempt to creating the function and line 28 is what I was hoping to have for every button's action. I'm not experienced with having arrays in functions so I that's where I'm lacking here. I know I'm really close to solving it but having some experienced minds to give it a once-over would be helpful. Thank you in advance!

[VC Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAQCz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see, all your buttons' actions is something like this:

```
    let billTotal = Double(subtotalText.text!)!
    let grandTotal = (billTotal * tipArray[x]) + billTotal

    //return grandTotal
    totalAmountLbl.text = String(format: "%.2f", grandTotal)
```

The only difference is the `x` value. To simplify your code, you can extract the whole thing into a method like this:

```
func outputGrandTotal(tipIndex: Int) {
    let billTotal = Double(subtotalText.text!)!
    let grandTotal = (billTotal * tipArray[tipIndex]) + billTotal

    //return grandTotal
    totalAmountLbl.text = String(format: "%.2f", grandTotal)
}
```

And in each of your buttons' actions, do a call like this:

```
@IBAction func fiveBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    outputGrandTotal(tipIndex: 0)

}

@IBAction func tenBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    outputGrandTotal(tipIndex: 1)

}

@IBAction func fifteenBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    outputGrandTotal(tipIndex: 2)

}

@IBAction func twentyBtn(_ sender: Any) {

    outputGrandTotal(tipIndex: 3)

}

@IBAction func twentyfiveBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    outputGrandTotal(tipIndex: 4)
}

@IBAction func thirtyBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    outputGrandTotal(tipIndex: 5)

}
```

To further simplify your code, you can give a `tag` to all your buttons. Then you just need one `@IBAction` method. In the method, access the button's tag. Like this:

```
@IBAction func tipButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    outputGrandTotal(tipIndex: sender.tag)
}
```

You connect all the button's action to the above method and give each button a tag. The five button's tag is 0, ten button is 1, fifteen button is 2 and so on.

Comment: thank you so much! That worked like a charm. I knew that the index of the array was the common denominator but I couldn't wrap my head around it. Also, thank you for the advice on simplifying the code to use the button's tag. I'll surely look into that. Thanks again!